# Why does MailAddress not reject the email address someName@gmail?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `MailAddress` to attempt to validate a given email.

I get a valid email when I give it a string like "someName@gmail".

I was expecting it to fail with a `FormatException` since the email is missing .com at the end. Why is it not failing to parse the email here?

```
public bool IsEmailValid(string emailaddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`x@host` is a legally formatted email address. The [`MailAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=netframework-4.7.1) only looks at the format of the string, not the validity of the address. You'll have to resolve the host name, send an email to the recipient and wait for the absence of a bounce mail or the presence of a return receipt to fully validate the address.

Answer (score 2):

`someName@gmail` is actually a perfectly valid email address, in that it conforms to the [email format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) (formally IETF [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1)).  However it is almost certainly not routable unless you happen to have a mail server on your local network with the DNS name `gmail`.

If you would like to check for this particular problem, I would suggest adding a second check that there is a dot after the `@` symbol.

**EDIT:** Please note that this is a business decision that you have to make.  By invalidating email addresses with a `.` after the `@`, you are breaking the standard email specification, however I feel that in perhaps 99.99% of cases dealing with *external* mail this is an acceptable tradeoff to make to prevent users mistakenly typing `myname@hotmail` or `myname@gmail` (I'd wager a common mistake among new Internet users).

This *could conceivably* block legitimate external email, say if I owned the TLD `tt` I could have a legitimate email address `bob@tt`, and mail handling systems like yours should handle my address without complaining.  However as it has been noted in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/721927/can-you-have-an-email-address-with-only-the-top-level-domain-as-the-domain-part), this is very uncommon.

Having said that, here's some code that would achieve this:

```
public bool IsEmailValid(string emailaddress){
  if (emailaddress == null || !emailaddress.Contains("@") || !emailaddress.Split("@")[1].Contains("."))
  {
    return false; // Doesn't contain "@" or doesn't contain a "." after the "@" 
  }

  try
  {
      MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
      return true;
  }
  catch (FormatException)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Unless you have a very limited range of possible email addresses, don't go trying to limit top level domains. For example only allowing `.com`, `.net` and `.org` would be a big mistake - as of writing there are over [1500 TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) which an email address could conceivably end in

Comment: Having said the above, I should also add that aside from conforming to specifications, the only way you can know if an email address is truly valid is by sending it and letting the network decide if it can be routed successfully to its destination.  Please don't try and filter out email addresses you *think* are not valid, there are many online forms and services that, for example, don't allow the `+` symbol before the `@`, even though this is a common and perfectly acceptable character.

Comment: Dots are not a required part of the specification. If you're not going to bother to resolve the host/domain name, you should not make any more assumptions about the address other than the three standard parts have non-zero length.  In other words, X@Y is legal and should not be dropped due to missing dots.

Comment: @jwdonahue you're absolutely right, I didn't say that it was a required part, in fact I specifically said that it is valid without.  My point is that in probably 99.99% of business cases where you are dealing specifically with external mail there is going to be a dot somewhere in the domain after the `@` symbol, but the user needs to determine if that is a valid assumption to make. I will clarify this, thanks.

Comment: @pcdev I'm sure a lot of those do it on purpose so you can't use the gmail multiple-address tricks. (As well as a lot that are just doing it because of poor design)

Comment: Ya, the likelihood that your code will be around at the turn of the century seems low as well, why not store two digit years?  You should have a reason to add restrictions on top of the standards.  The probability that the proposed restriction will enhance the user experience might just be on the same order of magnitude as the probability of encountering an email server name with no dots in it.

Comment: @immibis You're probably right, but a lot of people do use it and it's a frustrating experience if you do and a website doesn't let you.

Comment: @jwdonahue You can bet that companies like Google and Apple that have their own TLDs will start using `john_smith@google` and `john_smith@apple` in the future. And `me@localhost` would be pretty common for testing.

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm not arguing with you, you're probably right.  See my edit, this is something that needs to be weighed up against other business criteria.  In particular I've seen new users both say and sometimes enter `name@hotmail`.  It happens.

Comment: @immibis, Sure, many already do, but pcdev is looking for the dot on the domain side of the address.

Comment: @jwdonahue Oh, that dot was misleading you, I'll edit it out. The domain has no dots.

Comment: @immibis, Doh!  I totally missed the importance of the TLD.  Yes, I was just trying to figure out how to point out that new standards will be layered on top of existing ones.  Software that unduly limits the range of usability beyond what the standard allows, are likely to miss out on future usage patterns.

Comment: Also, there's millions of host and network files out their with special entries to save users from having to type so much.  In fact, lots of large organizations provide aliases in their internal DNS tables to enable short-cuts like X@gmail for instance.

Comment: @jwdonahue That's an extremely poor use of local DNS tables, to shorten email addresses.  That limits your data to your environment and ties it to a specific DNS table.  I accept that internally X@Y is common enough that it should be allowed.  Externally, however it is so extremely uncommon as to not be a concern for most mail systems, and allowing it will allow clearly incorrect (to you and I today) email addresses like `me@gmail`.  I'm clearly not the only one that thinks this: try creating a new Google & Facebook account for `test@gmail` both reject it - on the other hand Twitter allows it

Comment: @pcdev, I am talking about DNS servers that only serve the local networks, not visible to external hosts.  DNS is used in this manor for all sorts of useful key/value pairs.  I even know of server names that can only ever be resolved by their host names, no domain, even though the network they are on and the only clients allowed to attach to them are all within a registered domain.

Comment: @jwdonahue Oh, look: https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en

Comment: @pcdev, fully aware of that actually.  It's not relevant here.  You can't register a domain that is its own TLD, in other words, no domain named "COM" or "GMAIL", but GMAIL.GMAIL is legal.  That doesn't mean that X@Y is forbidden in the email system.  What people do with their own internal DNS is their own business.  BTW, it used to be user@hostname, not user@domainname and historically host names don't have a lot of dots in them (not that they can't).

Comment: @pcdev, Consider admin@localhost!  Not an uncommon event target.

Comment: @jwdonahue That's why I have specifically said that my addition relates to handling of *external mail* addresses.  If you're handling internal mail it definitely might break stuff.  It's a business decision.

Comment: So were two digit years and 5 bit character tables.